# supervisord autorestart max tries?

Tags: supervisord

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-values says you can use autorestart=true to restart on exit, but doesn't say how to give a maximum amount of restarts (within startsecs) before giving up. Is there a way to do this? Note: I'm not talking about the first startup, but about the event that a program crashes after, say, running fine for 10 days.

According to the docs, autorestart doesn't care about `startretries`:

> autorestart controls whether supervisord will autorestart a program if
>   it exits after it has successfully started up (the process is in the
>   RUNNING state).
>
> supervisord has a different restart mechanism for when the process is
>   starting up (the process is in the STARTING state). Retries during
>   process startup are controlled by startsecs and startretries.

Answer (score 6):

You should use startretries as well, ex of program configuration:

```
[program:consumer_example]
command=command example
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d 
numprocs=1                                      
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=10
user=USERNAME
```

As you can see I used startretries with 10, when you not inform into program it uses the default value (3).

Comment: Are you saying that `startretries` actually affects both restarts during startup, and restarts after the program has been successfully started and is in the `RUNNING` state?  The docs explicitly say "Retries **during process startup** are controlled by startsecs and startretries", but nothing about during RUNNING.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you need is to use the startretries parameter..

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?highlight=startretries#program-x-section-example

best regards

Comment: Does it actually work with autorestart? The way I read the docs for autorestart, startretries (now pasted into my answer) shouldn't have an effect in the RUNNING state.

Comment: Yeah.. i have forgot to speak about the startsec parameter, that permit you to control the moving from STARTING to RUNNING state. With the combinaison of startretries and startsecs i think you can make what you want to do..

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?highlight=startsecs#program-x-section-example

Comment: Are you saying that a program that crashes after 10 hours will move back into the STARTING phase?

Comment: No, it'll move back to the EXITED phase ! Then If autorestart is configured the process should restart to move to the RUNNING state.

http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#process-states

Comment: Any one knows why the supervisor failed to start a program (worker) which put the program to FATAL state after maximum tries to restart ?